WinForms application (.NET 6) always run as 32-bit in Microsoft Store
I've released a WinForms application in the Microsoft Store, but it only runs as 32-bit on a 64-bit Windows 11 OS. The application is developed using .NET 6 (C#) and compiled as "Any CPU". Is there a limitation in the "Desktop Bridge" msix files that only allows 32-bit?
The task manager displays the following:

I've tried to change settings in the solution- and project files, but no change.

I remember reading so place that Any CPU is run automatically as 32 bit.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093015/changing-from-any-cpu-to-x64

"Any CPU" should not automatically run as 32 bit. When running on my own computer, outside the Microsoft Store, it runs as a 64 bit process.

Does this answer your question? What does the Visual Studio "Any CPU" target mean?

@user246821, the application behaves according to the suggested article outside the Microsoft Store, but not inside the Store. If installed locally, either by a normal setup project, published as a Package, or run directly from the local drive, it loads as 64-bit. But when started from the Microsoft Store it always run in 32-bit mode. Due to memory limitations I need 64-bit.

The following may be of interest: Publish your app in the Microsoft Store.

After various attempts I see that "Any CPU" always defaults to 32-bit.
The only solution is to build a msix package combining x86, 64 and ARM64.
Neutral (Any CPU) should never be selected.

